# Baseline predictors parametres

Tags: algorithms, predictor, hyperparameter, nonparametric

I've implemented baseline predictors model. 
It trains on data: "`user_number item_number rating_ui`"
And then I need to predict raiting for "`user_number item_number`".
I use following formulas for biases:

```
b_ui = average_rating + b_i + b_u;
b_i = (sum_(by all items)(rating_ui-average_rating))/(lamda_2+items_count);
b_u = (sum_(by all users)(rating_ui-average_rating-b_i))/(lambda_3+users_count);
```

I tried to use Netflix constants lambda_2 = 25 and lambda_3 = 10. But it gives not enough accuracy. How can I optimize lambda_2 and lambda_3 using training data? There are to much data to use gradient descent.

Comment: @Chiffa I used SVD instead of baseline predictors at the end

Answer (score 0):

In chapter 5, page 149 of "Recommender Systems Handbook" by F. Ricci, L. Rokach, B. Shapira and P. B. Kantor it is suggested to use cross-validation over the dataset in order to find the best values for the regularization parameters